# Redirection from index to front page (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, indexing, directory

I installed Drupal on my website. It works perfectly but to reach the front page I'm systematically redirected to a page called "Index of" and I have to click on the subfolder drupal-7.12/ to reach the front page. So, the real url for my website i guess is
http://www.mysite.com/drupal-7.12

On my ftp server is organized like this:

Folder public_html
    -> Folder drupal-7.12 + a file .htaccess

There is another .htaccess file inside the folder drupal-7.12
I know that I have to modify one of them but i don't know which one and what i have to modify ?

I hope that someone will understand my problem and could help me
Thanks
ML

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you remove the folder in drupa.7.12 and move everything up one directory.  Basically you are set up as:

Mysite/drupal7.12

move all the contents of drupal 7.12 up one directory to your public_html folder

Or you need to edit the htaccess in the public_html folder to redirect you to that folder.  But that is going to cause some issues in the long run.